# Is this a semicolon between a method declaration and the method body?

Tags: c++, syntax

I programmed for many years in C and C++ (I now use C#), and I ran into the following C++ code:

```
std::vector<BYTE> authTag(authTagLengths.dwMinLength);
{
    BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
    BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(authInfo);
    authInfo.pbNonce = (PUCHAR)&origNonce[0];
    authInfo.cbNonce = origNonce.size();
    authInfo.pbTag = &authTag[0];
    authInfo.cbTag = authTag.size();
    bcryptResult = BCryptEncrypt
    (
        keyHandle,
        &encrypted[0],
        encrypted.size(),
        &authInfo,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &encrypted[0], encrypted.size(),
        &bytesDone, 0
    );
    std::cout << "Encrypted Data" << std::endl;
    for (auto val : encrypted)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << (0xFF & val) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm looking at. `authTag` appears to be a method. But it's followed by a semicolon, and then what appears to be a method body.

I've never seen a semicolon between the method declaration and it's body. Can someone explain what I'm looking at here?

Comment: Also watch out for your friend and mine, [the Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) and it's less vexing friends that give you a function declaration where you thought you were getting a variable definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all inside a function, right?

The first line defines a variable `authTag` of type `std::vector<BYTE>` and initialises it with a length.

The following code block is unrelated to that variable definition. The only reason why the following code is inside a separate code block is to create a more constrained scope: the variables inside that block go out of scope (and their destructors run) at the end of that scope, rather than at the end of the containing function.

Comment: Yes, this is inside a function. Okay, I am familiar with what you're talking about. The way it was formatted made it seem like it was different. But it appears you're right. Thanks.